# Different fakechroot behavior on Fedora and Ubuntu

Tags: chroot

Consider the following directory tree (`mychroot`):

```
mychroot/
├── proc
│   └── cpuinfo
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── ls
```

**On Fedora 20:**

```
$ fakechroot chroot ./mychroot/  /usr/bin/ls proc
cpuinfo
```

Version:

```
$ fakechroot --version
fakechroot version 2.9
```

**On Ubuntu:**

```
$ fakechroot chroot ./mychroot/  /usr/bin/ls proc
```

lists the /proc entries from outside chroot.

Version:

```
$ fakechroot --version
fakechroot version 2.17.2
```

What could be going on here? Thanks for any insights.

**Update:**

Definitely looks like a change in behavior. I installed 2.10 on Ubuntu and I see the same result as on Fedora (with 2.9):

```
$ /usr/local/bin/fakechroot --version
fakechroot version 2.10
$ /usr/local/bin/fakechroot chroot ./mychroot  /usr/bin/ls proc
cpuinfo
```

Filed an [issue](https://github.com/dex4er/fakechroot/issues/20) upstream.

Comment: Do you have the same configuration on both machines? specifically `FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH`.

Comment: @Gilles I have not set that variable on any of the distros. I have a feeling there could be a regressive behavior?

Comment: Check the configuration files in `/etc/fakechroot` and `~/.fakechroot`, not just the environment.

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is a systemwide env file in /etc/fakechroot, which it was loading. On Fedora there was none. Perhaps different packaging. However: ``fakechroot -e none ..`` fixes it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fakechroot can be configured to exclude some paths, i.e. those paths will refer to the same location inside the (fake) chroot and outside. This is especially useful for directories like `/dev` and `/proc` which it is useful to have everywhere as a lot of programs depend on them.

Excluded paths can be defined via:

- the `FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH` environment variable;
- a `FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH` setting in configuration files in `~/.fakechroot` and `/etc/fakechroot`, named `COMMAND.env` where *COMMAND* is the command invoked by `fakechroot` (e.g. `chroot.env`).

Check whether `/proc` is on the excluded list in Ubuntu via the environment, in `~/.fakechroot/chroot.env` or in `/etc/fakechroot/chroot.env`. In the Debian package, `/etc/fakechroot/chroot.env` adds `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` to `FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH`. If you don't want that, copy `/etc/fakechroot/chroot.env` to `~/.fakechroot/chroot.env` and edit the relevant line, or else pass the `-e` argument to specify a different configuration file (e.g. `fakechroot -e /dev/null chroot …`).

Comment: Will specifying FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH while executing the command override the setting in any configuration file? If so, can you give an example? ``FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH=/proc:/sys fakechroot chroot ./mychroot /usr/bin/ls proc`` doesn't seem to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Amit No, the configuration file appends to `FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH`. If you want to remove `/proc` from the list, you need to use a different configuration file.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, now I could get what I wanted by using "-e none" on 2.17, but the package included in Fedora is 2.9 which doesn't have, "-e" option. So, I removed *all* possible env files from Ubuntu, but it still doesn't obey the FAKECHROOT_EXCLUDE_PATH env variable. Can you suggest an alternative which would work with both versions?